# Return only unique objects from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Having the following array:

```
const arr = [{ id: 'A', version: 0, name: 'first' },
             { id: 'A', version: 1, name: 'first' },
             { id: 'B', version: 0, name: 'second' },
             { id: 'A', version: 2, name: 'first' },
             { id: 'B', version: 1, name: 'second' }];
```

I need to use this as input for two drop-downs.

For the first drop-down it should show in the list only two values, `A` and `B`.

For doing that:

```
const firstDropdownOptions = [...new Set(arr.map((el) => el.id))];
```

Unfortunately, this returns `['A', 'B']` which doesn't contain any information about the other properties.

It would be more useful to be like:

`[{ id: 'A', version: '0', name: 'first' }, { id: 'B', version: '0', name: 'second' }]`

Any ideas on how to make it return the above array?

Comment: `const firstDropdownOptions = arr.filter(({version}) => version === 0);`.

Comment: Why should `A` return the object with `version: '0'` and not `version: '1'`? In fact, `['A', 'B']` may be any thing like: `[{ id: 'A', version: '1', name: 'first' }, { id: 'B', version: '0', name: 'second' }]` or `[{ id: 'A', version: '2', name: 'first' }, { id: 'B', version: '0', name: 'second' }]` or `[{ id: 'A', version: '0', name: 'first' }, { id: 'B', version: '1', name: 'second' }]`  or ...

Comment: Yeah - but which `object` - there are 3 objects with `A` and 2 with `B`. So, what is the logic to choose which one of the objects for the letters?

Comment: @LeoMessi No, it works for your particular example only.

Comment: @Leo Messi I added an answer. I hope it helps as per the problem statement you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `id` and set all options for the second `select` by the selection of the first.

```js
const
    setOptions = id => groups[id].forEach(o => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = o.version;
        option.innerHTML = o.version;
        second.appendChild(option);
    });

    data = [{ id: 'A', version: 0, name: 'first' }, { id: 'A', version: 1, name: 'first' }, { id: 'B', version: 0, name: 'second' }, { id: 'A', version: 2, name: 'first' }, { id: 'B', version: 1, name: 'second' }],
    first = document.createElement('select'),
    second = document.createElement('select'),
    groups = data.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.id] ??= []).push(o), r), {});

document.body.appendChild(first);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
document.body.appendChild(second);

Object.keys(groups).forEach(k => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = k;
    option.innerHTML = k;
    first.appendChild(option);
});

setOptions('A');

first.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    let i = second.options.length;
    while (i--) second.remove(i);
    setOptions(first.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a short solution to this problem:

```
const result = arr.filter((value, index, self) => { 
    return self.findIndex(v => v.id === value.id) === index
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** As you are only returning id in `array.map()` method. Hence, it is giving you only unique Id's `[A, B]` in a new array. To get all the other properties you have to fetch via condition to check if `version === 0`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const arr = [{ id: 'A', version: 0, name: 'first' },
             { id: 'A', version: 1, name: 'first' },
             { id: 'B', version: 0, name: 'second' },
             { id: 'A', version: 2, name: 'first' },
             { id: 'B', version: 1, name: 'second' }];
             
const firstDropdownData = arr.filter((obj) => obj.version === 0);

console.log(firstDropdownData);
```